# how to unit test nest with fastify

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs, nestjs-fastify

I searched the documentation for Next, but I didn't find much on how to unit test `main.ts`

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter(),
  );
  
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Api')
    .addTag('Api', 'User API')
    .build();

  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);

  SwaggerModule.setup('user', app, document);

  await app.listen(process.env.CONTAINER_PORT, '0.0.0.0');

  console.log(`port: ${process.env.EXTERNAL_PORT}`);

}

bootstrap();
```

Comment: Why do you want to unit test the main? What specific logic do you want to test in there?

Comment: because of the covarege score of the tests

Comment: Ignore the file. If you have no logic you are looking to test (this all looks like unrelated configuration), then there's really no reason to write a unit test

Comment: Is there a way to disable it so it doesn't appear in coverage?

Comment: Depends on your test runner/coverage collector. Most have a way to ignore files by name or pattern